# How to achieve this type of button structure in android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

[image]

**Questions::**

1) The image above shows a series of buttons(4 visible and the remaining 2 will be shown once the user presses the left or right arrows) . Based on the buttons selected i need to show a particular layout of components just below the buttons. This looks like a Gallery of images about to be scrolled. How can i achieve this. Moreover if you see the images , it looks like tabs. But i cant implement tabs as these are not meant for holding different pages.

2) Also you can see the background of each button(which is in focus) , the upper roundrect could be done but what about the bottom curve at both ends.How can i achieve this. Please provide me an example(if any).

Thanks,

Comment: Read about Tab activity. http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136 or http://android.attemptone.com/layouts/custom-tabs/ And also read about scroll-able Tabs.

Comment: Can TabActivity hold different layouts or components of a single page. As the TabActivity is meant to hold different screens

Answer (score 1):

You could add buttons within a `HorizontalScrollView` in the upper part of the Activity's layout. The lower part would be a fragment, which you can switch around (using `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction`) with method called from the `onClickListeners` set to each button in the scrollview.

You should check this out: [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should probably have a custom layout that will hold the buttons, and when clicked, switches out which buttons are in which order and keeps track of which one is selected.

The way you will get the outward curved edge at the bottom will be to have the button use transparency around the edges, enough so that you have a background to an button like this:

```
.....................
.  _______________  .   <- Transparency around the edges of the box  
.  |              | .      to the dotted border.
.  |              | .
.  |              | .
.  |              | .
. /               \ .
./_________________\.
```

Note that you will need to have a selector for the source of the image button to have the reflection version when it is not selected and the version without the reflection when it is selected (like in your example picture.) Please not that the solution to this is going to need some custom classes and a lot of custom graphics. Good luck!